# Multiple onClick events

Tags: ajax, jsp, jsf

I have a JSF page, a drop down where values are getting fetched from service. 
Default is "Select from Drop Down" and a datePicker and a submit button.

I need to apply JS/AJAX validation here.

If a user clicks on Submit button without chosing any value from the drop down and the date. It should first diplay a message,

**1) If none chosen, first show a message - Please select a value from drop down.**

**2) if the value is selected from the drop down and date has not been selected  It should display a message " select a date".**

**3) if the date is selected and value is not selected from the drop down  It should display a message " select a value from the drop down".**

Both validation should be done on a single click on submit button.

Currently it's just checking if date is not selected. onclick event code is mentioned below.

**Drop Down**

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="valueList" value="#bean.values">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Select Action" itemLabel="Select Action" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{sampleService.sampleMethod}"
    var="SampleVar" itemValue="#{SampleVar}"
    itemLabel="#{SampleVar}">
    </f:selectItems>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**Submit button**

```
  <ui:define name="actions">

----h:inputHidden id="getAllDates"
value="#{serviceMethod.getAllDates}"-----
    <h:commandButton styleClass="inputbutton" valuGenerate" id="export"
    action="#{generate.someReport}" onclick="saveDate(); />
   </ui:define>
```

Passing all selected dates in hidden.
**OnClick event** this js function is written in another file.

> onclick="saveDate();"

```
function saveDate() {
    var dates = $('#selectDates').datepick('getDate');
    var datesValue = '';
    if(dates==null || dates=="undefined"){
    alert("Select Dates");
    return false;
    }
    if(dates!=null){
//    store in an array and return true
    }
```

Currently page is getting refreshed on every click on Submit button and alert message gets displayed only for date.

Can anybody help me in applying ajax call on submit button and displaying validation messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking too much in the JavaScript direction. Use JSF provided facilities. Use the `required` attribute to specify required inputs. Use `requiredMessage` attribute to specify the validation message. Use `<h:message>` to display the validation messages. Use `<f:ajax>` to submit (and validate) data by ajax.

So, this should do:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="action" binding="#{action}" value="#{bean.action}" required="true" requiredMessage="Please select action">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Select Action" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.actions}" />
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="actionMessage date" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:message id="actionMessage" for="action" />

<x:yourDatePickerComponent id="date" value="#{bean.date}" required="#{not empty action.value}" requiredMessage="Please select date">
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="dateMessage" />
</x:yourDatePickerComponent>
<h:message id="dateMessage" for="date" />
```

*(I have no idea what component you're using as date picker, just replace `x:yourDatePickerComponent` accordingly)*

Comment: Thank you For your reply, I have edited my question. <h:message id="actionMessage" for="action" />
this didn't work.

Comment: In the above example, it's for a `<h:selectOneMenu id="action">`. In your example you have a `<h:selectOneMenu id="valueList">`. Alter/align accordingly. It should be clear what and how a `<h:message>` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need ajax :

```
    function save() {
    var validated = true;
    var dates = $('#selectDates').datepick('getDate');
    var datesValue = '';

    var message;
    if(dates==null || dates=="undefined"){
        alert("Select Dates");
        message = "message1";
        validated = false;
        return false;
    }

    if( $('#idOfDropDown').val() != ''){
        message = "message2";
        validated = false;
        return false;
    }

    if(!validated){
        // preveent thr form from submitting
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahmad, page will get refreshed after validation message appears. 
thanks for reply....